# Sorting / Ordering in asp.net mvc 4 with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a controller that's returning a list of results. Some results get multiple hits, for example:

```
result x,
result x,
result x,
result y,
result z
```

I'm then trying to sort these results by the number of hits they have with this code here:

(orgs.Organisations is a list of Organisations i.e. results)

```
orgs.Organisations = orgs.Organisations
                         .GroupBy(f => f.Name)
                         .SelectMany(c => c.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name.Count()))
                         .ToList();
```

This is the closest I think I have gotten but its still not returning them in the correct order. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query orders items within group, not the groups. Make `OrderBy` call before `SelectMany`:

```
orgs.Organisations = orgs.Organisations
                         .GroupBy(f => f.Name)
                         .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                         .SelectMany(g => g)
                         .ToList();
```